# Layer cart overlay error

Tags: javascript, ajax, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

After update from 1.6.1.2 to 1.6.1.16 without updating the theme. When I'm adding product to the cart `.layer_cart_overlay` does not show anymore.
So now, that modal popup window doesn't appear, Chrome devtool said
[chrome error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do7cb.jpg) and Firefox devtool said:

> TypeError: product.attributes_full is undefined

So, is it enough to add `if (typeof product.attributes_full !== 'undefined')`?

My code, lines 732-748:

```
    updateLayer : function(product){
    $('#layer_cart_product_title').text(product.name);
    $('#layer_cart_product_attributes').text('');
    if (product.hasAttributes && product.hasAttributes == true)
        $('#layer_cart_product_attributes').html(product.attributes_full.replace(/\,/g,'<br>'));
    $('#layer_cart_product_price').text(product.price);
    $('#layer_cart_product_quantity').text(product.quantity);
    $('.layer_cart_img').html('<img class="layer_cart_img img-responsive" src="' + product.image + '" alt="' + product.name + '" title="' + product.name + '" />');

    var n = parseInt($(window).scrollTop()) + 'px';

    $('.layer_cart_overlay').css('width','100%');
    $('.layer_cart_overlay').css('height','100%');
    $('.layer_cart_overlay').show();
    $('#layer_cart').css({'top': n}).fadeIn('fast');
    crossselling_serialScroll();
},
```

Lines 346-354:

```
if (idCombination)
  $(jsonData.products).each(function() {
    if (this.id != undefined
      && this.id == parseInt(idProduct)
      && this.idCombination == parseInt(idCombination)
    )
      if (contentOnly)
        window.parent.ajaxCart.updateLayer(this);
      else
        ajaxCart.updateLayer(this);
  });
```

Link to full project: [ajax-cart.js](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9WeIcusLEfQT3haeVZGQ1QtY0U/view?usp=sharing)